# Does method report(_:withCompletionHandler:) send score even if your internet connection was lost?

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard, gkscore

I have a question about [GKScore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkscore). There is a method called [report(_:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkscore/1399252-report). What happens if you lose your Internet connection. Do I need to save my score and submit it later? Or the method itself solves it. Is it not automatically sent in the background?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's Game Center programming documentation:

> Your game should create the score object and report the score to Game
>   Center immediately after the score is earned. This sets the date and
>   time accurately and ensures that the score is reported correctly. If
>   for some reason the score could not be reported because of a network
>   error, Game Kit automatically resends the data when the network
>   becomes available.

So you don't have to do anything.  Reference to the docs is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW19).

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try it putting the plane mode.

But if you try to call this method without internet it will return an **error**.

You could get the internet connection status using the reachability. If you use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) it have integrate a very good reachability system.

If your game need internet to play you can block your principal screen using:

```
import Alamofire

extension NetworkReachabilityManager {
    static var isConnectedToInternet: Bool {
        return NetworkReachabilityManager().isReachable
    }
}
```

Else you can save your request to send it when you have internet.
The NetworkReachabilityManager will send you a notification when internet was enable and disable.